# IBM IMM Remote Control

Tags: remote, ibm

I've installed an IMM module for a server that has to be controlled remotely. Now, while the general panel works greatly, I can't run the remote control.

The server is behind a firewall and the RC works greatly in LAN, so I guess that is a matter of port.

Which one should I open?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here](http://www.redbooks.ibm.com/abstracts/tips0511.html) is the list of ports you need to have open.

**Edit:** Do the normal network problem debugging. Can you ping the server? Does  `tcptraceroute` to the appropriate port work OK? Can you telnet to the appropriate port?

If RC works over LAN but does not remotely it does look like a networking issue.

Comment: Thank you, but the list didn't solve the situation: I'm still unable to remotely control the machine.

Comment: but you marked this as the answer...?